# Perl: Iterating through an xml parent node for a particular value of one child node and comparing values for other child nodes under that parent node

Tags: xml, perl, iterator

I have an autoyast file (SLES configuration). It has entry for multiple bonds and network cards. I need to find each of whether it's type bond or NIC and then need to iterate through rest of parameters to verify if they are correct.

```
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("setuplan_1.xml");

my $count_interface = $doc->findvalue("count(//interface)");
print "total interface $count_interface\n";
for ( my $iterator = 1; $iterator < $count_interface; $iterator++){
print "Iterator value $iterator";
my $device_name = $doc->findnodes("//networking/interfaces[\@config:type="list"]/interface[$iterator]/device");
if ( $device_name =~ m/bond(\d+)/){
print $device_name;
}
elsif ( $device_name =~ m/(p(\d+)p(\d+)|em(\d+))/){
print "alom device";
}
}
```

Sample XML document for autoyast

```
    <networking>
    .........
    <interfaces config:type="list">
    <interface>
    <bonding_master>yes</bonding_master>
    <bonding_module_opts>xxxxx</bonding_module_opts>
    <bonding_slave0>emxx</bonding_slave0>
    <bonding_slave1>pxpy</bonding_slave1>
    <bootproto>static</bootproto>
    <device>bondx</device>
    <ipaddr>x.x.x.x</ipaddr>
    <name>Management/Quorum</name>
    <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
    <startmode>auto</startmode>
    <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
    </interface>
    <interface>
    <bonding_master>yes</bonding_master>
    <bonding_module_opts>xxxxxxxx</bonding_module_opts>
    <bonding_slave0>pxpy</bonding_slave0>
                <bonding_slave1>pxpy</bonding_slave1>
                <bootproto>static</bootproto>
                <device>bondx</device>
                <ipaddr>x.x.x.x</ipaddr>
                <name>xxxx</name>
                <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
                <startmode>auto</startmode>
                <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
         </interface>
             ..........
       <interface>
                <bootproto>none</bootproto>
                <device>pxpy</device>
                <name>This adapter is part of BOND and is disabled</name>
                <startmode>hotplug</startmode>
                <usercontrol>NO</usercontrol>
            </interface>
            <interface>
                <bootproto>none</bootproto>
                <device>pxpy</device>
                <name>This adapter is part of BOND and is disabled</name>
                <startmode>hotplug</startmode>
                <usercontrol>NO</usercontrol>
            </interface>
        .........
   </networking>
```

In this XML file there are multiple interface tags, each for bond device and NIC cards. Based on these I need to look for other nodes in that interface and compare values to verify

Error that I receive is

```
Bareword found where operator expected at autoyastcheck.pl line 13, near ""//networking/interfaces[\@config:type="list"
    (Missing operator before list?)
String found where operator expected at autoyastcheck.pl line 13, near "list"]/interface[$iterator]/device""
syntax error at autoyastcheck.pl line 13, near ""//networking/interfaces[\@config:type="list"
Execution of autoyastcheck.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: please Format your code properbly

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem are the nestes double quotes. You can escape them or by using backslash:

```
my $device_name = $doc->findnodes("//networking/interfaces[\@config:type=\"list\"]/interface[$iterator]/device");
```

Comment: Or use signle quotes for attribute values, XPath accepts both.

Comment: Backslashing quotes is ugly and rarely needed in Perl. As @choroba points out, using single quotes for the attribute works fine here. But another (even more flexible) option is to use the `qq[...]` operator for the outer double-quotes - `$doc->findnodes(qq[//networking/interfaces[\@config:type=\"list\"]/interface[$iterator]/device])`

Comment: ... but you've still escaped the quotes ;)

Comment: `$doc->findnodes(qq[//networking/interfaces[\@config:type="l‌​ist"]/interface[$it‌​erator]/device])`